# gitlab-ci.yml only on master branch

Tags: gitlab

I have a gitlab-ci.yml file like this, and want to run it only on Branch Master. If there is a push into develop branch the Pipeline should **NOT** start.

I tried with 'only' keyword, but it shows an Error.

```
stages:
  - info
  - build
  - test
  - review
  - cleanup
  - deploy-dev
  - integration-test
  - deploy-test
  - system-test
  - deploy-production

only:
  refs:
    - master
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To define a trigger rule for every stage you can use the *workflow* keyword, like this:

```yaml
    workflow:
      rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
          when: never
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master'
```

This has to be on the "root" of your yaml, as it is not part of any job in particular.

In the example above, I am telling the pipeline to avoid running when a repository tag is pushed and to run only when a commit is done in the master branch.

You can use this as a base and add other conditions to trigger the stages in the pipeline, the complete documentation on this matters can be found here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow

Comment: It says bad indentation on `when: never`

Comment: Note that 'when' needs to have one less space before. I tried putting in an edit but it says edit queue is full (probably fixing this problem).

Comment: I accepted the edit proposed by @finwo.

Answer (score 2):

I thin you have an indentation problem here.
It should be something like:

```
stages:
 - job_1
 - job_2
 - ....
 - job_n

job_1:
  stage: job_1
  ....
  only:
    refs:
      - master

job_2:
  stage: job_2
  ....
  only:
    refs:
      - master
....
```

You need to define the target branch for each stage.

Comment: No i get an Error that the gilab-ci.yml file is invalid....

Comment: @Petziferum Same issue here. But I find a related [link](https://newbedev.com/how-to-run-gitlab-ci-only-for-specific-branches-and-tags)