# Is there a way to ensure that a commit belongs to a specific branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I use tags to deploy to a specific environment using a block

```
only:
    - tag1
    - tag2
```

But tags can be placed in different branches.

Therefore, a situation may occur when a developer puts the "prod" tag in his branch and the deployment goes to prod environment.

Is there a way to prevent this, or somehow make sure the tag belongs to a specific branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: There is no way to ensure a commit only belongs to a specific branch. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69209160/19238131) however may point you in the right direction to solve your problem.